# How can I get a Cook Islands primary domain (.ck)?

Tags: domain

On GoDaddy's support page, it says if you are resident in Asia, you can get a .ck domain.  Is it possible to get a .ck domain if I live in the US?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you have to have proof of living within that region. mainly I think as the url spells out .co.ck maybe people were trying to buy them up as joke domains. Infamous one from the UK www.trashbat.co.ck You can appeal for one though